# Получение всех вложенных каталогов из указанной директории

Tags: php

Нужно определить все директории которые есть в указанной директории, но с учетом вложенных в них директорий.

Приведу пример:

Есть директория `site_root` в ней есть папки: `lib`, `controllers`, в которых тоже есть свои папки, а в них могут быть другие папки и так далее.

Задача в том, что бы получить полные пути до последней папки.

примерно так:

```
site_root/lib/папка/еще_папка/последняя_папка
```

и так для всех папок в этом самом `site_root`.
Решил через рекурсию, если кому интересно то вот код:

```
private static function searchDir($root){
    $scan = scandir($root);
    foreach($scan as $dir){
        if(is_dir($root.self::DS.$dir) and $dir != '.' and $dir !='..'){
            static::$dirlist[]=$root.self::DS.$dir;
            static::searchDir($root.self::DS.$dir);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: вы на каком то фреймворке хотите или на чистом php?

Comment: Без фреймворков.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

думаю поможет это

```
$dirs = array_filter(glob('*'), 'site_root');
print_r( $dirs);
```

посмотрите [glob](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.glob.php)

---

есть еще вариант такой, корорый выводит список папок как дерево

```
function listFolderFiles($dir){
    $ffs = scandir($dir);
    echo '<ol>';
    foreach($ffs as $ff){
        if($ff != '.' && $ff != '..'){
            echo '<li>'.$ff;
            if(is_dir($dir.'/'.$ff)) listFolderFiles($dir.'/'.$ff);
            echo '</li>';
        }
    }
    echo '</ol>';
}

listFolderFiles('site_root');
```

---

или можно собрать в массив

```
$folders = array();

function listFolderFiles($dirFrom, $dir){
    $ffs = scandir($dir);

    foreach($ffs as $ff){
        if($ff != '.' && $ff != '..'){
            if(is_dir($dir.'/'.$ff)) {
                $folders[] = $dirFrom . $ff;
                listFolderFiles($dirFrom . $ff, $dir.'/'.$ff);
            }
        }
    }

}

listFolderFiles('site_root');
```

---

нашел еще одно решение в официального сайта php [пример из scandir](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.scandir.php#68856)

Comment: Не решает проблему вложенности, а именно в ней и заключается вся загвоздка.

Comment: @alestro Ну я вижу эта функция себя рекурсивно вызывает для директорий - значит решает.

Comment: Комментарий был до изменения ответа и про рекурсию я как раз и забыл, благодарю.

Answer (score 1):

```
function glob_dirs_reсursive($path, $ret = array())
{
    $dirs = glob(rtrim($path,"/")."/*", GLOB_ONLYDIR) or array();
    foreach ($dirs as $path)
    {
        $ret[] = $path;
        $ret = glob_dirs_reсursive($path, $ret);
    }
    return $ret;
}
$dirs = glob_dirs_reсursive("site_root");
```

По поводу принятого ответа - два примера из трех в нем нерабочие, а один не отвечает поставленным условиям.

По поводу собственного решения автора - наивно думать, что вхождения текущей и родительской директории всегда будет выводиться первыми. Плюс использование глобальной переменной неоправдано.

Comment: согласен с вашем мнением. но не хорошо минусоват, вед автору ответ помогло. А оптимизировать это 2е. И есть там есть 3 не нудных, предлодили бы убрать, так правильнее

Comment: По поводу глобальной переменной я вообще не понял, где вы её нашли, ну да ладно. А по поводу моей наивности(я так понял вы про array_shift(), то это я уже исправил проверкой через блок if ), да и это играет роль разве что передать sorting_order отличный от SCANDIR_SORT_ASCENDING, да и то это решаемо.

Answer (score 0):

```
$directory = 'some_dir/'; // откуда пляшем
$path_arr = [];
$it = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($directory));
while($it->valid()){
    if ($it->isDir()) {
        $path_arr[] = $it->getPath();
    }
    $it->next();
}
print_r($path_arr);
```